# ¿Por qué mis sesiones en PHP 7.4 se cierran solas?

Tags: php, sesiones

La sesion php 7.4 se cierra sola, ya modifique en archivo php.ini y reinicie apache : `session.gc_maxlifetime = 100000` y `session.cookie_lifetime = 100000` e igual se cierra a los 3o minutos aproximadamente.

Tambien he usado:

```
ini_set('session.cache_expire', 600);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 36000);
```

Uso php puro, como puedo resolver este problema ?

Comment: Busca en el código que funciones de sesión estás utilizando (que empiezen con "session_"), quizas estás llamando a session_abort(), o session_regenerate_id(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal yo tenia el mismo problema con una pagina que tengo, lo resolví de la siguiente manera, vas a tener que usar en cada hoja la siguiente función:

```
<?php
    $lifetime=86400;
    session_start();
    setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
?>
```

Esta función tendrías que ponerla al inicio de cada una de las paginas que manejes con la sesión, sin embargo si no quieres batallar, agrégala en una hoja en blanco PHP y solo llámala al inicio de las paginas en las que tengas la sesión con un requie, en mi caso lo agregue en una hoja solo y le llame VALIDA_SESION.PHP y esta la llamo así en las hojas donde manejo la sesión:

```
<?php
    require('VALIDA_SESION.PHP');
?>
```

Esta fue la manera en la que solucione el tema de las sesiones, espero que te ayude de mucho mi respuesta, saludos!!